# CentOS 5 : error in installing php-imap

Tags: centos, php, imap

can someone please help me with this CentOS 5 question?

I am trying to install php-imap, i tried

`yum install php-imap`

but I am getting the following output:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.hostingxtreme.com
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: mirror.team-cymru.org
 * updates: mirror.beyondhosting.net
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-imap.x86_64 0:5.1.6-44.el5_10 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-44.el5_10 for package: php-imap
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
php-imap-5.1.6-44.el5_10.x86_64 from updates has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-44.el5_10 is needed by package php-imap-5.1.6-44.el5_10.x86_64 (updates)
Error: Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-44.el5_10 is needed by package php-imap-5.1.6-44.el5_10.x86_64 (updates)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

I already have php-common installed, I ran "yum install php-common" and got the following output

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.hostingxtreme.com
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: mirror.team-cymru.org
 * updates: mirror.beyondhosting.net
Setting up Install Process
Package matching php-common-5.1.6-44.el5_10.x86_64 already installed. Checking for update.
Nothing to do
```

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: I would really prefer to get some help or explaination instead of voting down my question, thank you

Comment: I don't get the downvote. This is a non-obvious problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have something corrupted somewhere in the RPM database or yum cache. I'd clear them all out and rebuild them.

First the RPM db:

```
rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db.*
rpm --rebuilddb   # In later versions, this command changed to  rpmdb --rebuilddb
```

Then the yum cache:

```
yum clean all
```

Then bring everything back in sync with the latest on the remote repositories:

```
yum distro-sync
```

Finally, try installing the package again.

Comment: I am not very good at linux, the server is live and i dont want to miss things up, if i do as you say above, will this effect other programs installed? thank you.

Comment: @TMMDev then you probably shouldn't have root access.

Comment: @TomO'Connor thank you for your notice, i have configured the server from zero and installed all programs, i am just asking the proffesionals if this will effect the server or not.

Comment: @TMMDev If you follow the directions _exactly as given_ then you will not cause any damage.

Comment: @MichaelHampton i followed your instructions, however, yum distro-sync   outputs yum help, i tried to install the imap package "yum install php-imap" i got the same problem in the main question (it is not working), what should i do now?

Answer (score 0):

In that case, I would prefer to remove php-common completely and then try to install php-imap.

```
yum remove php-common*
yum install php-imap
```